# Repeat functions for x amount of times in Swift using Xcode 6.4

Tags: xcode, swift

I have an app that uses 3 functions which use NSTimer which are called consecutively or one after the other. I would like for these functions to be repeated for x amount of times because I have an @IBOutlet called `repsField` which creates a value that is stored in the global variable `repetitions`which is by default set to 0 until a user changes this value using the @IBOutlet.

Basically, I'd like to multiply the amount of times that the functions are called by the global variable `repetitions`. How can I do this?

Screenshot:

[image]

Here's an example of one of the timers...

```
func start1() {
    if timerRunning==false{ // Timer will start
        timer=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Counting1"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timerRunning=true
    }
}

func Counting1(){
    timerCount+=1 timerLabel.text="\(timerCount) secs"
    if timerRunning==true && timerCount >= timerMaximum {
        stop()
        intervalAlert()
        start2()
    }
}
```

Please get back to me as soon as possible

Comment: I figured this is a good place to start http://i.gyazo.com/77275b38ca12ff206d90fa9b82459e36.png

Comment: Am I missing something, or would a simple for loop do the trick?

Comment: @Kendel I tried to do a for loop but I think I did it wrong. Xcode returned an error saying something about missing a generator.

Comment: Can you post the code you used?

Comment: `for x in repetitions{ 
start1()
}`
I literally wanted start1() to execute the x number of times that repetitions is. Like, start1() multiplied by repetitions. Make sense?

Comment: That is the syntax you use for something like an array. I have posted an answer with syntax for a counted for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop:

```swift
for count in 1...repetitions {
     // do stuff
}
```

Check out: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html

Comment: I thought repetitions was an integer? The variable repetitions in my answer needs to be an integer...

Comment: I changed it to 
`        for count in 0...repsField.text {
            start1()
        }`
And now the error seems to have gone.

Comment: Repetitions is an integer. The user can only enter an integer... I'm so confused :[

Comment: You aren't using the code I posted... You replaced `repetitions` with `repsField.text` which is a string. You need to use an integer. Please check the link I posted for help with syntax.

Comment: I used repetitions and that error went away. Now, I'm presented with a new error -> http://gyazo.com/4e2bf8324f4301eb54c37d058776067b

Comment: I want the variable to hold the repsField value which is the @IBOutlet for the text field... It should be stored as an integer so I don't see the problem :3

Comment: You are trying to cast integer to a textField. Retrieve the text from the text field, and covert it to an integer. You can't set an integer equal to a UITextField.

Comment: I did `repetitions = repsField.text.toInt()!` which fixed that error. Although, now the `for count in 1...repetitions` thing doesn't work. For some reason, the code executes and doesn't go onto that for statement... :[ debug time

Comment: Please help me. I took your advice and now I've got further! 

This is my code -

`    var repetitions = 1`

`    func startBasedOnReps(){
        if repetitions==0{
            endWorkoutAlert()
            stop()
        }
        for count in 1...repetitions {
            start1()
            workoutAlert()
        }
    }`

I'm having a problem right now where once a timer has completed, the for count 1 some how causes start1() and workoutAlert() to just spam themselves and it's really annoying. I literally want them to run through and not just keep starting/stopping. Ew. :(

Comment: This is no longer an issue with the for loop. It sounds like you need to work on the functions you made, and consider the answer @Rob gave